# Skip a tab while switching among tabs in TabBarView

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter app, I use a simple tab-bar. I used the code from the flutter website and updated to make sure that I can keep the state of each tab using AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin.

I have 3 tabs and each tab is fetching a list of data (why I need to use AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin) from my backend API.
The problem is that when I switch between first and 3rd tabs (Page1 and Page3), the middle tab keeps rebuilding over and over again until I switch to that tab (Page2) and only at that point it doesn't get rebuilt anymore.
Every rebuild results in fetching data from API and that's not desirable.
Below, i have included a simplified code to reproduce this issue.
You can see in the debug console once switching between 1st and 3rd tab (without switching to 2nd tab) that it keeps printing "p2" (in my real app, it keeps fetching data for the 2nd tab).

Is there a way to switch between tabs without other tabs in between being built/rebuilt?

This is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TabBarDemo());
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Page1(),
              Page2(),
              Page3(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page1State createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<Page1> {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    print('p1');
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Icon(Icons.directions_car),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page2State createState() => _Page2State();
}

class _Page2State extends State<Page2>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<Page2> {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    print('p2');
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page3 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page3State createState() => _Page3State();
}

class _Page3State extends State<Page3>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<Page3> {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    print('p3');
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this isn't a bug with flutter, but ultimately comes down to your implementation.
Please take a look at the code I wrote for you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class FakeApi {
  Future<List<int>> call() async {
    print('calling api');
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
    return <int>[for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) i];
  }
}

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp() : super(key: const Key('MyApp'));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => const MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage());
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage() : super(key: const Key('MyHomePage'));
  static const _icons = [
    Icon(Icons.directions_car),
    Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
    Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => DefaultTabController(
        length: _icons.length,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [for (final icon in _icons) Tab(icon: icon)],
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Center(child: _icons[0]),
              StaggeredWidget(_icons[1]),
              Center(child: _icons[2]),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
}

class StaggeredWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const StaggeredWidget(this.icon)
      : super(key: const ValueKey('StaggeredWidget'));
  final Icon icon;

  @override
  _StaggeredWidgetState createState() => _StaggeredWidgetState();
}

class _StaggeredWidgetState extends State<StaggeredWidget> {
  Widget _child;

  Timer _timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _timer = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 150), () {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() => _child = MyApiWidget(widget.icon));
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => _child ?? widget.icon;
}

class MyApiWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApiWidget(this.icon, [Key key]) : super(key: key);
  final Icon icon;
  @override
  _MyApiWidgetState createState() => _MyApiWidgetState();
}

class _MyApiWidgetState extends State<MyApiWidget>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  final _api = FakeApi();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('building `MyApiWidget`');
    super.build(context);
    return FutureBuilder<List<int>>(
      future: _api(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) => !snapshot.hasData
          ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : snapshot.hasError
              ? const Center(child: Icon(Icons.error))
              : ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                    title: Text('item $index'),
                  ),
                ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```